# HTML5 video doesn't play in IE, mobile browsers

Tags: mobile, html5-video, internet-explorer-10

I'm having a problem where an html5 video is not loading/playing in IE10 or on either Mobile Chrome or Safari on iPhone or Android. The video plays fine on all other desktop browsers. Not sure what the issue is. The mp4 was saved with baseline H.264 codec.

The video in question is at the top of the page at res.dallasnews.com/test/jhancock/videoTest2

Any ideas or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am having the same problem. How did you overcome this problem?